# Determine the selected days of the week from row in sysschedules table?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Based on the SQLServer's [dbo.sysschedules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/dbo-sysschedules-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) table:

> freq_type  int
>
> How frequently a job runs for this schedule.
>
> freq_interval  int
>
> Days that the job is executed. Depends on the value of freq_type. The
> default value is 0, which indicates that freq_interval is unused. See
> the table below for the possible values and their effects.

If the `freq_type` column is 8 (weekly) and the `freq_interval` column is 38

How do you determine the selected days of the week given their values:

```
1,2,4,8,16,32,64 for Su,M,T,W,Th,F,S
```

I'm looking for SQL Server or C# answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft seems to have an example in their C# documentation on enumeration types. Elegant enough for me. I adjusted the Day enum assignments to match those that SQLServer uses for the freq_interval.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum#enumeration-types-as-bit-flags

```
[Flags]
public enum Days
{
    Sunday    = 0b_0000_0001,  // 1
    Monday   = 0b_0000_0010,  // 2
    Tuesday = 0b_0000_0100,  // 4
    Wednesday  = 0b_0000_1000,  // 8
    Thursday    = 0b_0001_0000,  // 16
    Friday  = 0b_0010_0000,  // 32
    Saturday    = 0b_0100_0000,  // 64
}
public class FlagsEnumExample
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var a = (Days)38;
        Console.WriteLine(a);
        // Output:
        // Monday, Tuesday, Friday
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like bit-fiddling.  I would suggest fixing your data model.  Such micro-efficiencies are usually a bad idea in relational databases.

In any case, you can use bit operations:

```
select concat_ws(',',
                 (case when freq_type & 1 then 'Su' end),
                 (case when freq_type & 2 then 'M' end),
                 (case when freq_type & 4 then 'T' end),
                 (case when freq_type & 8 then 'W' end),
                 (case when freq_type & 16 then 'Th' end),
                 (case when freq_type & 32 then 'F' end),
                 (case when freq_type & 64 then 'S' end)
                )
```

Comment: this is the design of the MS SQLServer's sysschedules table. The data model is beyond my control

Comment: Unfortunately, there's a lot of stuff in SQL Server's underlying objects that have poor designs, @c_Reg_c_Lark . There's still system tables that use `text` and `image`, XML stored in string datatypes, and SPs that use a `CURSOR` that would really benefit from a set-based approach. Some of these they "don't fix" because it would be a "breaking change", however, the only people that things would break for would be other (now) poorly designed MS objects. This is probably why some things have been deprecated for 15+ years and still not removed. Hopefully they'll bite the bullet one day.

Comment: @ThomA How would you improve the design of the `freq_type` column in the `sysschedules` table?

Comment: @CoderAbsolute I am not the author of this answer.